# No Routes Match 'GET' Ruby on Rails / AngularJs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails API and angular as frontend .I placed the angular code in Public directory and it was working fine until the permalink implementation (i.e facebook , google ,twitter web crawlers ) . When i share a link on e.g facebook and click on it , it redirects me to the specific post .But when i click on any link now it does not work and refreshing the page gives me

> No route matches [GET]  .

Whole Angularjs code is in `public/folder`

Here is my Gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'rails-api'
gem 'spring', :group => :development
gem 'mysql2'

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth'

gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-base64'
gem 'rmagick' 

gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'

gem 'httparty'
gem 'rpush'

gem 'angular_rails_csrf'
gem 'has_permalink'
```

I also tried with `gem 'angular-rails-templates'` `gem 'sprockets'` and according to `'angular-rails-templates'` documentation i added js requirements and angular dependency . But it is not taking dependency and showing

> 'App' can not load

error due to that . Any help will be appreciating .

**public/configs/config.js**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','GooglePlusProvider', '$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,GooglePlusProvider, $locationProvider){  $routeProvider
        .when('/popup',{
            templateUrl: 'views/admin/popup_text.html',
            controller:  'adminCtrl',
             resolve: {
                auth: function ($auth, $location) {
                    return $auth.validateUser().catch(function(err){
                        console.info('not authenticated', err);
                        $location.path('/');
                    });
                }
            }
        })


        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    }])
```

**Note :** I can not change the place of my Angular code because my work is about to end and then I faced this dirty issue

Comment: can you please post the template and the configurations

Comment: @RajarshiDas dear kindly look at the config.js I updated

Comment: Can you post the code where app is defined? Do you have a module named 'App'?

Comment: please also show your routes.rb